# shorthand notation numerical integration

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, notation

Is there a shorthand for a numerical integration operator? Basically I have some Gaussian quadrature rule
$$\int_\Omega f(x) \mathrm d x \approx \sum_i^N f(x_i) \omega_i$$
and instead of writing the right hand side and messing with indices, I would like to have some shorthand notation like
$$\mathcal{N}\int_\Omega f(x) \mathrm d x.$$
I was wondering if there is a standard for that or if I have to define my own?

Comment: I think you notation is a perfectly good choice. I personally have never seen special notation.

Comment: I've seen $Q[f]$ where Q stands for quadrature

Comment: Let me add to this after all those years. We ended up publishing a paper with the $Q[f]$ notation, which I like the most so far. It emphasizes that it is a functional of $f$ and does not use any continuous math operators which could be misleading in my opinion. It is often important to make a distinction between the analytical quantities and their approximations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there is no standard.   A typical notation I've seen is
$I_N(f)$; other parameters can be included if they are relevant, e.g. you might have $I_N(f; a,b)$ if $a$ and $b$ are the endpoints of the interval and are not fixed in the case at hand.
You can define your own notation, but make sure to include the definition when you use it.

Comment: thank you for your answer! I will probably have to define my own...

Answer (score 1):

How about 'f(x) as opposed to f'(x)?  Suggested by my students after a discussion...  we call it the Guillot Bengey Zhou (GBZ) notation...